# BroadcastReceiver not being called?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I using a Alarmmanager in the launch activity to execute something in BroadcastReceiver repeatedly, but BroadcastReceiver not being triggered. my code is as follow:

MainActivity.class:

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent gpsintent =new Intent(getBaseContext(),gps_sendback_alarm_receiver.class);
PendingIntent.getService(getBaseContext(), 0, gpsintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, now.getTimeInMillis(), int_gps_sendback_period, pendingIntent);
```

gps_sendback_alarm_receiver.class:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//send back the GPS location
}
```

manifest:

```
<application>
<receiver android:name="com.example.xmobiler.gps_sendback_alarm_receiver" android:enabled="true"/>
</application>
```

anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

you are creating the variable `gpsintent` but the alarmmanager gets `pendingIntent` that is not assigned in your example code

Comment: I check the logcat,I see that AlarmManager is triggered,but gps_sendback_alarm_receiver is not,why?
V/AlarmManager(2276): waitForAlarm result :4                       
V/AlarmManager(2276): trigger ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKEUP

Comment: I use "adb shell dumpsys alarm" to check whether the AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP is registered,the answer is not. why the log in logcat is different from adb?

Comment: can you show us the code where the variable `pendingIntent` is defined and used?